# Trying to change image dynamically for every bodyPart item but getting same image for every bodyPart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rapidapi

I am working on fitness app using react js where there is a list of bodyparts. I wanted to have a seperate image for each body part but getting same image for all

BodyPart.js

```react
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';

const BodyPart = ({ item, setBodyPart, bodyPart}) => {
    
    const image = require(`../assets/images/bodypart/${bodyPart}.jpg`);
   
    return (
        <Stack type="button"
            alignItems="center"
            justifyContent="center"
            className="bodyPart-card"
            sx={{
                borderTop: bodyPart === item ? '4px solid #ff2625' : '',
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                borderBottomLeftRadius: '20px',
                width: '270px',
                height: '280px ',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                gap: '47px'
            }}
            onClick={()=>{
                setBodyPart(item);
                window.scrollTo({top:1800, left:100, behavior:'smooth'})
            
            }}
        >
            <img
                src= {image}
                alt='dumbell'
                style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }}
            />
            <Typography fontSize="24px" fontWeight="bold" color="#3A1212">
                {item}
            </Typography>
        </Stack>
    )
}

export default BodyPart
```

HorizontalScroll.js

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import BodyPart from './BodyPart';
import { ScrollMenu, VisibilityContext } from 'react-horizontal-scrolling-menu';
import RightArrowIcon from '../assets/icons/right-arrow.png';
import LeftArrowIcon from '../assets/icons/left-arrow.png';
import ExerciseCard from './ExerciseCard';


const LeftArrow = () => {
    const { scrollPrev } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

    return (
        <Typography onClick={() => scrollPrev()} className="right-arrow">
            <img src={LeftArrowIcon} alt="right-arrow" />
        </Typography>
    );
};

const RightArrow = () => {
    const { scrollNext } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

    return (
        <Typography onClick={() => scrollNext()} className="left-arrow">
            <img src={RightArrowIcon} alt="right-arrow" />
        </Typography>
    );
};


const HorizontalScrollbar = ({ data, bodyParts, setBodyPart, bodyPart}) => {
    
    return (<ScrollMenu LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow}>
        {data.map((item) => (
            <Box
                key={item.id || item}
                itemId={item.id || item}
                title={item.id || item}
                m="0 40px"
            >
                {bodyParts ? <BodyPart item={item} 
                    setBodyPart={setBodyPart} bodyPart={bodyPart}/>: <ExerciseCard exercise={item}/> }
            </Box>
        ))}
    </ScrollMenu>
)
}

export default HorizontalScrollbar
```

SearchExercises.js

```js
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {Box, Button, Stack,TextField, Typography} from '@mui/material';

import {fetchData, exercisesOptions} from '../utils/fetchData';
import HorizontalScrollbar from './HorizontalScrollbar';
import images from './images'

const SearchExercises = ({setExercises,bodyPart,setBodyPart}) => {

  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [bodyParts, setBodyParts] = useState([])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchExercisesData = async () => {
      const bodyPartData = await fetchData('https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList',
      exercisesOptions);
      setBodyParts(['all',...bodyPartData]);
   }

   fetchExercisesData();
  }, [])
  
  const handleSearch = async () => {
       if(search) {
        const exercisesData = await fetchData(
          'https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises',
          exercisesOptions
        );
       
        const searchedExercises = exercisesData.filter(
          (item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search)
                 || item.target.toLowerCase().includes(search)
                 || item.equipment.toLowerCase().includes(search)
                 || item.bodyPart.toLowerCase().includes(search),
        );
        setSearch('');
        setExercises(searchedExercises);
       }
  }

  return (
    <Stack alignItems="center" mt="37px"
    justifyContent="center" p="20px">
        <Typography fontWeight={700}
        sx={{fontSize:{lg: '44px', xs:'30px'}}}
        mb="50px" textAlign="center">
            Awesome Exercises You <br/>
            Should know
        </Typography>
        <Box position="relative" mb="72px">
        <TextField 
        sx={{
            input: {fontWeight: '700',
            border :'none', 
            borderRadius:'4px'
        },
        width :{lg:'800px', xs:'350px'},
        backgroundColor : "#fff",
        borderRadius:'40px'
        }}
        height="76px"
        value={search}
        onChange={(e)=>{setSearch(e.target.value.toLowerCase())}}
        placeholder="Search Exercises"
        type="text" />
        <Button className="search-btn"
        sx={{
            bgcolor:'#FF2625',
            color:"#fff",
            textTransform :'none',
            width:{lg:'175px', xs:'80px'},
            fontSize :{lg:'20px', xs:'14px'},
            height:'56px',
            position : 'absolute',
            right:0
        }} onClick={handleSearch}>
          Search
        </Button>
        </Box>

        <Box sx={{position:'relative', width:'100%', p:'20px'}}>
             <HorizontalScrollbar data={bodyParts} bodyParts
              setBodyPart={setBodyPart} bodyPart={bodyPart} isBodyParts/>
        </Box>
    </Stack>
      
  )
}

export default SearchExercises
```

[image: getting this as output]

I wanted to have separate image for each body part. I tried to create array of all bodyParts data with images and name but that also didn't work in this scenarios.

This "https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList" API returns below data

[image: Added data return by the API]

I have already render the required data as individual box here. I just wanted to apply image for each bodyPart separately currently it is applying same image

Comment: What is the value of `bodyPart` that is passed to `SearchExercises`? This prop is passed all the way through `HorizontalScrollbar` to `BodyPart` where it's the same for all `BodyPart` components. I suspect you really want to grab a property off the `data` prop, (*`bodyParts` array*) that is passed to `HorizontalScrollbar`. We can't see the data that the `"https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList"` API endpoint returns so we can't even guess as to what you really wanted to render. Can you [edit] to include example API response data, and what you need to render from it?

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the question with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is *some* `bodyPart` prop being passed to `SearchExercises` all the way through `HorizontalScrollbar` to `BodyPart`... which is the same value for all values the `HorizontalScrollbar` component is mapping.

The `HorizontalScrollbar` component's `data` prop ***is*** the body parts data that should be mapped, not the passed `bodyPart` prop.

SearchExercises

```
const SearchExercises = ({ activeBodyPart, setExercises, setBodyPart }) => {
  ...
  const [bodyParts, setBodyParts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchExercisesData = async () => {
      const bodyPartData = await fetchData(
        'https://exercisedb.p.rapidapi.com/exercises/bodyPartList',
        exercisesOptions
      );
      setBodyParts(['all', ...bodyPartData]);
   }

   fetchExercisesData();
  }, []);

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <HorizontalScrollbar
      data={bodyParts}
      bodyParts
      setBodyPart={setBodyPart}
      activeBodyPart={activeBodyPart}
    />
    ...
  );
```

HorizontalScrollbar

```
const HorizontalScrollbar = ({ activeBodyPart, data, bodyParts, setBodyPart }) => {
  return (
    <ScrollMenu LeftArrow={LeftArrow} RightArrow={RightArrow}>
      {data.map((bodyPart) => (
        <Box
          key={bodyPart}
          itemId={bodyPart}
          title={bodyPart}
          m="0 40px"
        >
          {bodyParts
            ? (
              <BodyPart
                activeBodyPart={activeBodyPart}
                setBodyPart={setBodyPart}
                bodyPart={bodyPart}
              />
            ) : <ExerciseCard exercise={bodyPart} />
          }
        </Box>
      ))}
    </ScrollMenu>
  )
}
```

BodyPart

```
const BodyPart = ({ activeBodyPart, setBodyPart, bodyPart}) => {
  const image = require(`../assets/images/bodypart/${bodyPart}.jpg`);
   
  return (
    <Stack
      type="button"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
      className="bodyPart-card"
      sx={{
        borderTop: bodyPart === activeBodyPart ? '4px solid #ff2625' : '',
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderBottomLeftRadius: '20px',
        width: '270px',
        height: '280px ',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        gap: '47px'
      }}
      onClick={() => {
        setBodyPart(bodyPart);
        window.scrollTo({ top: 1800, left: 100, behavior: 'smooth' });
      }}
    >
      <img
        src={image}
        alt='dumbell'
        style={{ width: '70px', height: '70px' }}
      />
      <Typography fontSize="24px" fontWeight="bold" color="#3A1212">
        {bodyPart}
      </Typography>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: Got it thanks for the solution.. now it's working as expected.